# How to modify the logging call so that it contains contextual information?

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to create a `Logger` class based on the `logging` facility provided in `Python 2.7`. There are quite a lot of examples demonstrating how to customize the logging and intercept (modify) various facilities by using custom Handlers and Adapters that inherit from the original `logging.Adapter` or `logging.Filters` classes.

Especially this is a very helpful resource: [Logging Cookbook](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-loggeradapters-to-impart-contextual-information)

The issue I am having is that as the examples provided in the above link demonstrate some specific context based tweaking, I am struggling with finding a way to include `trace` data into my logging.

I know that I can pass that with the extra parameter, without messing around with the actual message. However, the ideal solution for me would be to implement this as a `Filter` or a `Formatter`.

In case of a formatter that looks like this:

```
format='%(asctime)-15s %(name)-5s %(levelname)-8s {%(trace)s} %(message)s'
```

... And a custom Formatter class to inherit from the `Formatter` class and modify the log stream:

```
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a filter which injects contextual information into the log.
    """

    def filter(self, record):

        record.trace = # Do something to receive the trace data?
        return True
```

... Then finally comes the custom Logger class:

```
class Logger(object):
def __init__(self, name):
    self.console_formatter = '%(asctime)-15s %(name)-5s %(levelname)-8s {%(trace)s} %(message)s'
    self.syslog = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    self.syslog.setFormatter(self.console_formatter)
    self.syslog.setLevel(DEBUG)

    f = ContextFilter()
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    self.logger.addFilter(f)

def debug(self, msg, extra=None):
   self.logger.debug(msg, extra=extra)
```

... And inside any function/module call such as the one below:

```
log = Logger(logger_name)

def main_B():
    log.debug('This is a debug message: %s.', 'banana')
```

Should give me:

```
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 logger_name DEBUG {__main__.main_B()} This is a debug message: banana
```

In theory the `%(trace)` key in the formatter will be populated with the incoming trace information. However, I am not quite sure how to implement that final bit.

***--- EDIT (1) ---***

I keep looking for a solution and I am aware that we can have `%(funcName)` etc in the formatter, however I cannot stop thinking that there must be a way to pull out that record and inject a new value into the `%(trace)` section.

```
setattr(record, "trace", getCurrentTrace())
```